# Running github actions for `uses` in another directory

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

My maven repository is in `./java` directory. I want to run maven test in `./java` directory, but I got following error:

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/github/workspace). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my workflow:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build:
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: java
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Run maven test
        uses: xlui/action-maven-cli@master
    
        with:
          lifecycle: 'clean package test'
```

It seems that `working-directory` is useless, how can I fix it?

Comment: when you get directory error try to [actions/checkout@v2](https://github.com/actions/checkout) first

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`working-directory` can only be applied to `run:` steps (e.g it does not work on actions)

The action `xlui/action-maven-cli@master` currently doesn't allow to inform a `path` to execute the maven commands.

**You could either**

- use [another (similar) action available on the Github Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=maven%20cli) which allows to inform a `directory path` before executing maven commands,
- open a PR to update the `xlui/action-maven-cli` action, adding an input `path` (or `env` variable) to perform a `cd` command before executing the maven commands,
- install `maven` directly on your workflow within a step(for example [setup maven action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-maven)), before running the maven command directly on another step (without uses the action) with `run: |` with a `cd ./java` before executing `sh -c "mvn clean package test"`,

**Something like this (for the 3rd option)**:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
  - name: Install maven
    run: |
      ...
  - name: Run maven command
    run: |
      cd ./java
      mvn clean package test
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I finally solved the problem by installing maven and add `-f` parameter to specify the maven test directory. 
One thing I want to mention is that the official action for maven's install only take effect in root directory, so `cd ./java & mvn install` will lead to 'command not found: mvn'